# DISTINCT and CONCAT togheter

Tags: mysql

I need to create unique `SEO` words for website by adding - to `distinct` words.
I tried query

```
UPDATE url_alias SET `keyword = (SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT( keyword, '-' ));
```

but this query adds `-` to all words. What is wrong with this query?

Example: Words are Acer, Acer, Acer-, Apple, Apple, Apple- and these should be finally Acer, Acer-, Acer--, Apple, Apple-, Apple--

Table example in [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07894/1).

Comment: What is the table structure ?

Comment: When you write " adding - to distinct words", do you mean you only want to update those keywords which are unique?

Comment: @Pablo-Francisco-Pérez-Hidalgo I have some word duplicated or even some words are there 4 times. Lets say Acer, Acer, Acer, Acer. I need them to be Acer, Acer-, Acer--, Acer---.

Comment: @androza Then try my answer, it should work

Comment: @xdazz table url_alias, columns are url_alias_id, query, keyword. query is the link to the webpage, keyword is seo word.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE url_alias U1 SET keyword = 
(SELECT CONCAT( keyword, '-' ) from url_alias group by keyword) U2 
where U2.id=U1.id;
```

Comment: Tnx! But this also adds - to all words, i have some words duplicated like Acer and Acer, but i need only one to be Acer and other Acer- this is why i have to use distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TSEL SELECT keyword FROM url_alias GROUP BY keyword HAVING COUNT(keyword) = 1;
UPDATE url_alias SET keyword = CONCAT( keyword, '-' ) WHERE keyword IN (SELECT keyword  FROM TSEL);
```

This is:

1. Create a temporary table containing all unique keywords: This is, they are not repeated at different rows.
2. Updating those keywords contained in TSEL.

TSEL will be automatically deleted when your session is finished. Nevertheless you can delete it explicitly using:

```
DROP TABLE TSEL;
```

**EDIT**
If you want to ignore case as well as already inserted '-' characters, you will have to normalize **keyword** when the time to calculate candidates to update comes. In this case, your new SQLs should be:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TSEL SELECT UCASE(TRIM( BOTH '-' FROM keyword)) AS keyword FROM url_alias GROUP BY UCASE(TRIM( BOTH '-' FROM keyword)) HAVING COUNT(1) = 1;
UPDATE url_alias SET keyword = CONCAT( keyword, '-' ) WHERE UCASE(TRIM( BOTH '-' FROM keyword)) IN (SELECT keyword FROM TSEL);
```

If you consider "Acer" and "Acer-" as different:

```
CREATE TABLE TSEL SELECT UCASE(keyword) AS keyword FROM url_alias GROUP BY   UCASE(keyword) HAVING COUNT(1) = 1;
UPDATE url_alias SET keyword = CONCAT( keyword, '-' ) WHERE UCASE(keyword) IN (SELECT keyword FROM TSEL);
```

Comment: Tnx! I'll give it a try!

Comment: Unfortnately it does'nt work. If there is Acer, Acer, Acer then it adds - to one Acer and if i run query again then somehow it adds - again to Acer- so it will be Acer-- not to another Acer.

Comment: @androza Are these "Acer", "Acer", "Acer" strings exactly equal or may keyword field differ in at least one character? Could you edit your question to paste these rows? Anyway, try with the change I made in my answer

Comment: @androza Remember to regenerate TSEL before the UPDATE.

Comment: Acer, Acer, Acer and acer- are for example in the column so one difference is this acer-. I see that your query adds - to only those values which are only one. So when i query then acer- get another - but all Acer values stay the same. I also edited my question.

Comment: @androza Edited my answer again to adapt it to your new needs.

Comment: Thank You very much for your time but still nothing. :( I created an example here [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07894/1) Added it to the question also.

Comment: @androza In your example they are not being updated because my solution consider that "Apple" and "Apple-" are the same edited the answer to add a version where that constraint/assumption is removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE url_alias SET `keyword` = `keyword` + '-'
```

Answer (score 0):

> *I need to create unique SEO words for website by adding - to distinct
>   words. ...*
>
> *but this query adds - to all words. What is wrong with this query?*

You can use a `WHERE` condition to filter and set values to specific occurrences.

**Example**:

```
UPDATE url_alias SET keyword = CONCAT( keyword, '-' )
where keyword = ?
```

Change the where condition as desired to match an occurrence and execute.

Comment: Tnx! But i have about 6500 words and i dont know how many are the same and words are changing every day. :)

Comment: You however need a where condition to limit the update to specific words. If you can come-up with some condition on that `where` clause, someone can give you a possible solution.